# Using SUM in Laravel in more than one column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working in laravel and I have a table with multiple columns like including `cust_name`, `amount`, `discount`,  `return`.

How can I add the `amount`, `discount`,  `return` values having same `cust_name` entry?

```
            $sum = DB::table('customer')->groupby('cust_name');
            DB::table('customer')->Insert([                 
                    'Amount'=>$sum->sum('DueAmount'),
                    'discount'=>$sum->sum('discount'),
                   'return'=>$sum->sum('return'),];
```

It is not entry any values nor returning any error.

Comment: Are you only trying to select the aggregated values? Or are you trying to insert a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to select aggregated values of multiple columns, you could try using a `raw()` select with something like this:

```
$selectResult = DB::table('customer')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(DueAmount) as "TotalDueAmount", 
                            sum(discount) as "TotalDiscount",  
                            sum(return) as "TotalReturnAmount"'))
                ->groupBy('cust_name')
                ->get();


$insertResult = DB::table('customer_total_pending)
                ->insert(
                ['total_due' => $selectResult->TotalDueAmount, 
                 'total_discount' => $selectResult->TotalDiscount, 
                 'total_return' => $selectResult->TotalReturnAmount]
                );
```

I recommend you take a good read over the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: I am trying to insert added values from customer table to customer_total_pending table......

Comment: I have no context into your table/model structure but see edits for a way to do your insert.

Comment: It gives same previous results...I tried adding sum query in each column but it takes like forever to upload my large csv data of around more than 800K row entries